# Apk download from url using simple html dom in php?

Tags: php, curl

$url='https://download.apkpure.com/b/xapk/Y29tLm5nYW1lLmFsbHN0YXIuZXVfMTI3MzI0XzEwZGUxNjFk?_fn=QXJlbmEgb2YgVmFsb3IgNXY1IEFyZW5hIEdhbWVfdjEuMTguMi4xX2Fwa3B1cmUuY29tLnhhcGs%3D&k=29543182844b6888260e3002d062de685a1fb080&as=a156f79b8014c24ac0f963e178801da25a1d0df8&_p=Y29tLm5nYW1lLmFsbHN0YXIuZXU%3D&c=2%7CGAME_ACTION';

Get Apk file from this url.
Please anyone help me it's always redirect to home.

When i run this url on browser it's start download but when i put on 
curl it's redirect it's homepage.

Answer (score 0):

> Solution 1

This should work for smaller files

```
<?php

    set_time_limit(0);
    $curlSession = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://d-01.winudf.com/b/xapk/Y29tLm5nYW1lLmFsbHN0YXIuZXVfMTI3MzI0XzEwZGUxNjFk?_fn=QXJlbmEgb2YgVmFsb3IgNXY1IEFyZW5hIEdhbWVfdjEuMTguMi4xX2Fwa3B1cmUuY29tLnhhcGs&_p=Y29tLm5nYW1lLmFsbHN0YXIuZXU%3D&as=a156f79b8014c24ac0f963e178801da25a1d0df8&c=2%7CGAME_ACTION&k=63ae0c088841e46f08add313bfdceafe5a1f774a');
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $data = curl_exec($curlSession);
    curl_close($curlSession);
    file_put_contents('test.apk', $data);
?>
```

> Solution 2

If you have larger file you need to download them as a chunk to avoid memory limit issues

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
global $offset, $chunk_size;

$offset = 0;
$chunk_size = 1024 * 512;
$break = false;

while (!$break) {
    $break = download();
}

function download(){

    global $offset, $chunk_size;

    $range = $offset . '-' . ($offset + $chunk_size);


    $curlSession = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://d-01.winudf.com/b/xapk/Y29tLm5nYW1lLmFsbHN0YXIuZXVfMTI3MzI0XzEwZGUxNjFk?_fn=QXJlbmEgb2YgVmFsb3IgNXY1IEFyZW5hIEdhbWVfdjEuMTguMi4xX2Fwa3B1cmUuY29tLnhhcGs&_p=Y29tLm5nYW1lLmFsbHN0YXIuZXU%3D&as=a156f79b8014c24ac0f963e178801da25a1d0df8&c=2%7CGAME_ACTION&k=63ae0c088841e46f08add313bfdceafe5a1f774a');
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RANGE, $range);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($curlSession);
    curl_close($curlSession);
    file_put_contents('test.apk', $data, FILE_APPEND);

    if (!$data) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Seems your file is very large so it could exceed the PHP memory limit. Try solution 2. that download files as a chunk of 512KB , it works fine

Comment: it's takes so much time to download apk file

Comment: Is your internet is faster? If yes try to increase the value to mb `1024 * 1024 * 1;` //1 MB

Comment: No it's download but half of apk download.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your url gives a [`http 302 found` redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302), and your code ignores the redirect request (but your browser doesn't). luckily you can tell curl to auto-follow redirects just like your browser does, like this:

```
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
```